# Force render ViewPager in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

In my android app, I have a `Button` that changes color of `ViewPager`'s background by changing color stored in `SharedPreference`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    sPref=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    int color=sPref.getInt("BACKGROUND", Color.DKGRAY);

    if (color==Color.DKGRAY){
        SharedPreferences.Editor sEdit= sPref.edit();
        sEdit.putInt("BACKGROUND", Color.RED);
        sEdit.commit();
    }
    else{
        SharedPreferences.Editor sEdit= sPref.edit();
        sEdit.putInt("BACKGROUND", Color.DKGRAY);
        sEdit.commit(); 
    }
}
```

Background color is changed in my `ViewPager` like this

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View page= inflater.inflate(R.layout.card , null);
    TextView tc= (TextView) page.findViewById(R.id.txtCard);
    tc.setText("Card "+position);
    tc.setBackgroundColor(sPref.getInt("BACKGROUND", Color.DKGRAY));

    ((ViewPager)container).addView(page,0);

    return page;
}
```

**My problem:** When I change background color of my `ViewPager`, since the current page and 2 pages around are already loaded at the time I change background, they don't show change in background. So I want to force render them. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can:
Get the views for the loaded page and set the background yourself. (Using: `YOUR_ADAPTER.getItem(position)` )

Or, simply try:
`notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter

Comment: what is `_inboxAdapter`?

Comment: There is no `getItem` method in `PagerAdapter`. It just shows `getItemPosition()` method. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thought you were talking at FragmentPagerAdapter.
You need to save the View in the getItem method. ANyway the best way is notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I called `notifyDataSetChanged()` method on the adapter from the `onClickListner` of the `button`. There seems no effect in the pages that are already rendered. Now where should I change background of pages that has already been rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Note you are actually changing the bg color of the individual page hosted by the pager and not the ViewPager itself.  If you want to change the color of the ViewPager, just set its color and make sure your pages (cards) have transparent backgrounds; or, take Givi's advice and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` and in your adapter apply the updated bg color.

Comment: I called `notifyDataSetChanged()` after changing color. Now where should I change background of pages that has already been rendered?

Comment: What you'd probably want to do is update your bg color in the shared pref then call <code>notifyDataSetChanged()</code>.  Then, in your adapter when <code>getItem</code> is called you create/update your Fragment and update the bg color of the page before returning it.